# Unable to upload and download files from S3 bucket from my own computer

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

As the title states, I am unable to upload or download files from an S3 from my computer.

My team and I are working on a Netcore 2.1 + React project where we let our user upload their resumes and profile pictures as well as downloading them from an S3 bucket. That data is stored in an S3 Bucket that we set up and we set up the API context with Amazon.S3.Transfer. None of my team mates have any issues uploading or downloading images from the APIs that were setup to do such operations but me. My computer has Windows 10 Education Edition as a side note

The exception that I get when I try to upload a file is the following:

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10051): A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

My teammates tested the APIs and they work as intended except on my computer which I assume is not configured properly. I've played with my Firewall settings by adding my localhost server 5000 and 5001 to my outbound rules to see if that fixed the issues. I also turned off my firewall as another test. Some more info: I have a docker container running as well

I'm not sure what I need to look at to figure out this issue so some indication to where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could do a test using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command to see whether your computer can successfully communicate with AWS. That would mostly eliminate network and firewall issues.

Comment: Please share your code sample to upload data. May be there is something missing or need some changes in your code to make it work.